# How to convert php code to html source code?

Tags: php, html

I need to display html source code form other php file.
I have two file

code.php

index.php (I hope I can convert the code.php to html source code.)

code.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <body> <?php $color = "red"; echo $color; ?> </body> </html>
```

index.php (I hope I can convert the code.php to html source code.)

```
$php_to_html = file_get_contents("code.php");   
$html_encoded = htmlentities($php_to_html);  
echo $html_encoded;
```

but when i run the index.php file, the result is

```
 <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <body> <?php $color = "red"; echo $color; ?> </body> </html>
```

but I hope I can see the result is

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <body> red </body> </html>
```

any idea how can i do this ,thanks!!!

Comment: if you just want to see the output of `code.php` inside of `index.php` why not just `include` it?

Comment: I want to see the source code of code.php to be html inside of index.php, thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to execute the PHP, so include it and capture the output:

```
ob_start();
include("code.php");
$php_to_html = ob_get_clean();
$html_encoded = htmlentities($php_to_html);  
echo $html_encoded;
```

If you want the HTML to be rendered as HTML then don't use `htmlentities()`.

Optionally (not the best way) but you can execute it by retrieving from the URL:

```
$php_to_html = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/code.php");
$html_encoded = htmlentities($php_to_html);  
echo $html_encoded;
```

Answer (score -1):

Buffer output and include it:

```
ob_start();
include_once('code.php');
$html = ob_get_clean();
```

By using output buffering, any output is not sent to the browser, but instead kept in memory. This allows you to run the code, and get the output as a variable. ob_get_clean() flushes the buffer (in this case into our $html variable), and then stops buffering, allowing you to continue as normal. :-)

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.